# Problem to Segmentation fault with memset function

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to allocate memory for a 2D matrix but I get a segmentation fault.

```
int** inicializarMatriz(int **matriz, int vertices){
int i;
matriz=(int**) calloc(vertices,sizeof(**matriz));
for(i=0;i<vertices;i++){
    matriz[i]=(int*) calloc(vertices,sizeof(matriz[i]));
    memset(matriz[i],-1,vertices*sizeof(matriz[i]));
}
return (int **)matriz;}
```

How I can solve it?

Comment: Why do you have the parameter `matriz` whose value you never use?

Comment: All of the `sizeof` expressions are wrong too, you could try following the pattern `p = calloc(N, sizeof *p);`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are wrong with the first allocation memory.

```
matriz=(int**) calloc(vertices,sizeof(**matriz));
```

It should be

```
matriz=(int**) calloc(vertices,sizeof(*matriz));
```

Because you want to create vertices sub-array with the format *(matriz+i). So the correct size is sizeof(*matrix).

And one one more, it depends on your pass argument in the main function. Suppose you declare 2 pointer:int *array & int **array. When you pass them in your function, it will return differ result.

Comment: You should push all you code. It is easy for analyzing

Answer (score 0):

Install a tool called valgrind. Run your program through valgrind. It will tell you the exact cause of the segfault, what line it occurred on and why it occurred. Valgrind is essential for problems like this.

Also... I think that you are seriously confused in your use of the sizeof() function... and several other things.

I see one definite segfault which I marked //Problem

```
int** inicializarMatriz(int **matriz, int vertices)
{
    int i;

    //Problem --> matriz=(int*)calloc(vertices,sizeof(int*));

    for(i=0;i<vertices;i++)
    {
        matriz[i]=(int*) calloc(vertices,sizeof(int*));
        memset(matriz[i],-1,vertices*sizeof(int*));
    }

return matriz;
}
```

matriz is the input to your function. C maps that data to static memory. You are trying to write over that static memory, which will cause a SEGFAULT.

You can read static memory. You can change what it points at ( if it is a pointer and points to something malloced )... but you can't write over it.

Install and run valgrind on it. It will tell you all of this

Comment: Avoid type-size errors like `matriz[i]=(int*) calloc(vertices,sizeof(int*));`.  Use [`p = calloc(N, sizeof *p`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59402782/problem-to-segmentation-fault-with-memset-function#comment104994440_59402782)

Comment: That wasn't a correction that was meant to actually run... it was meant as a teaching tool to guide your thinking. You code has many problems. It's not even possible for me to fix it, because it fundamentally does not make sense.

The biggest of which is this: You have a function input that you never use. You immediately overwrite it ( which causes a SEGFAULT ) and ignore the input completely. That's a broken concept. It doesn't make any sense.